# Windows Forms Based Authentication (FBA) with persistent cookies in node.js

Tags: .net, node.js, cookies, forms-authentication, webdav

I want to open a MS Office Document via a WebDAV URL with authentication. I have it currently working with Basic Auth via SSL. This works but prompts for a login everytime you open the document. You can save the credentials but you're still prompted everytime and this is bad UX.

I've read that you can use Forms Based Authentication with persistent cookies (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2019105) but I cannot find an implementaiton of this outside the .NET world. I want to use node.js but am prepared to use any *nix open-source tech.

I assume that I'll have to get my users to use Internet Explorer, drop a correctly configured cookie, configure the security correct zone (intranet) for my domain and maybe display the correct OPTIONS header with the WebDAV request.

Has anyone done/seen/heard of this? Can anyone point me to some documentation or implementations?

Thanks.

**Note.** I don't think I want Windows Authentication, ie. Windows send me the username/password of the current user. This would require LDAP integration that I want to avoid at the moment. I just want the user to login once to my web app and then WebDAV resources to magically work (without the secondary authentication).

Comment: I might be missing a trick here. It's possible the IE shares the entire cookiebin with Office and attaches the cookies to the request headers... Thus it's up to me to come up with the solution. Will check tonight and come back to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blow me away. If the website is in the "Local Intranet" security zone; Internet Explorer shares your cookiebin with Office. So if you make a HTTP(S) request from Office (ie. to a webdav resource), they're sent too and you can use them for authentication.

Note I've only tested this over HTTPS with a self-signed certification, it may behave differently over HTTP.

I don't know which security setting within Local Intranet Zone it is, if I find out I will update the answer.